# TeeChart Colorgrid Performance with lots of Data Points

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I am writing an application in Visual Studio Express [C#], and I need to display 12 ColorGrids [128 x 128] at the same time, in realtime.

This is how I setup my chart:

```
        tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
        tChart1.Aspect.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
        tChart1.Legend.Visible = false;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Title.Text = "R";
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(0, 127);
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Increment = 20;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Title.Text = "D";
        tChart1.Axes.Left.SetMinMax(0, 127);
```

And then I init the ColorGrid like this:

```
        for (int d = 0; d < 128; d++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < 128; r++)
            {
                ColorGrid.Add(r, 0, d);
            }
        }
```

And then, in realtime, all I do is I update the YValues in some for-loop which covers the complete 128 x 128 range:

```
        ColorGrid.YValues[index] = value;
```

And after the for loop, I call:

```
        ColorGrid.BeginUpdate();
        ColorGrid.EndUpdate();
```

I currently have this for 12 TChart controls, which are displayed together on a Form.

I also tried combining the 12 charts into one big chart, by plotting 12 graphs as a 6 x 2 "sub-plot" graph, and that only made a small performance difference.

Is there a way to get 10+fps with:

either 12 separate [128 x 128] graphs, or one [128*6 x 128*2] graph???

If I have left anything unclear, please let me know :-)

Thank you

JD

Answer (score 1):

To improve the ColorGrid drawing time is a feature request already present in Steema's wish list (TF02016286).

Also note that, in general, as more points and elements of the chart to be drawn (grid lines, gradients, etc) more time is needed to draw the chart. So I'm not sure if it can be improved to the point you require.

A tip I don't see implemented in your example is to hide the ColorGrid Pen. This improves a bit the performance:

```
ColorGrid.Pen.Visible = false;
```

Also note `ColorGrid.BeginUpdate()` and `ColorGrid.EndUpdate()` are thought to be called before and after Clearing and repopulating the series respectively, not both together and after modifying the series values.